# SVN: Batch to force full diff between all files (local/repository)

Tags: svn, batch-file, comparison, commit

Is there a possibility to make a full compare between the checked out version of files and the repository via batch without doing something and list all files which are changed?

We've got the problem, that our devs reporting that not all files are commited and to be sure that it is really a technical problem, it would make sense to have a simple possibility to check it before commiting by executing this batch.

We're using Tortoise SVN Client 1.7.6 together with SVN 1.7.4. On Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in batch but it's easy using tortoise.
tag your working copy (use workingcopy option at tag menu)

then go to repo browser and compare the 2 url's

Comment: I don't think this is a solution because if Tortouise would detect the difference, it would commit the changed files also. But this is the problem.